# Convert octal string to decimal string in C++

Tags: c++

What is the easiest way to convert string holding octal number into string holding decimal representation of the same number?

I could convert it into int value using strtol, then convert into string again using stringstream:

```
string oct_number("203"); 

// converts into integer
int value = strtol(oct_number.c_str(), NULL, 8);

// converts int to decimal string
stringstream ss;
ss  << value;
string dec_number = ss.str();
```

But: is there any quicker way to do it? 
I have a rather poor understanding of the stringstream class, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string result;
Try
{
   result = std::to_string( std::stoi( oct_number, 0, 8 ) );
}
catch ( ... )
{
//...
}
```

Comment: He said he wanted to convert it to decimal so shouldn't it just be `std::stoi(oct_number)`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 He wants to convert one string into another string.

Comment: He said he wanted the *decimal* representation if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Read his post one more. It is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

In c++11 you can use `string dec_number = to_string (value);`.
Also you can use `sprintf` but you will need some buffer:

```
char buf[64];
sprintf(buf,"%d",value);
string dec_number = buf;
```